# Dovecot 2 /auth-userdb permissions

Tags: file-permissions, dovecot

Error in log file:

```
 userdb lookup: connect(/var/run/dovecot/auth-userdb) failed: Permission denied 
(euid=5000(vmail) egid=5000(vmail) missing +r perm: /var/run/dovecot/auth-userdb, 
euid is not dir owner)
```

Section of 10-master.conf:

```
service auth {
  # auth_socket_path points to this userdb socket by default. It's typically
  # used by dovecot-lda, doveadm, possibly imap process, etc. Its default
  # permissions make it readable only by root, but you may need to relax these
  # permissions. Users that have access to this socket are able to get a list
  # of all usernames and get results of everyone's userdb lookups.
  unix_listener auth-userdb {
    #mode = 0600
    #user = root
    #group = root
  }

  # Postfix smtp-auth
  unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/auth {
    mode = 0666
  }

  # Auth process is run as this user.
  #user = $default_internal_user
}

service auth-worker {
  # Auth worker process is run as root by default, so that it can access
  # /etc/shadow. If this isn't necessary, the user should be changed to
  # $default_internal_user.
  #user = root
}
```

Permission of /var/run/dovecot directory:

```
drwxr-xr-x.  4 root  dovecot 4096 Jan 10 14:00 dovecot
```

and listing of /var/run/dovecot directory:

```
drwxr-xr-x.  4 root    dovecot  4096 Jan 10 14:00 .
drwxr-xr-x. 14 root    root     4096 Jan 10 13:36 ..
srw-------   1 root    root        0 Jan 10 14:00 anvil
srw-------   1 root    root        0 Jan 10 14:00 anvil-auth-penalty
srw-------   1 root    root        0 Jan 10 14:00 auth-client
srw-------   1 dovecot root        0 Jan 10 14:00 auth-login
srw-------   1 root    root        0 Jan 10 14:00 auth-master
srw-------   1 root    root        0 Jan 10 14:00 auth-userdb
srw-------   1 dovecot root        0 Jan 10 14:00 auth-worker
srw-------   1 root    root        0 Jan 10 14:00 config
srw-------   1 root    root        0 Jan 10 14:00 dict
srw-------   1 root    root        0 Jan 10 14:00 director-admin
srw-------   1 root    root        0 Jan 10 14:00 director-userdb
srw-rw-rw-   1 root    root        0 Jan 10 14:00 dns-client
srw-------   1 root    root        0 Jan 10 14:00 doveadm-server
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root    root       25 Jan 10 14:00 dovecot.conf -> /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root    root     4096 Sep 23 15:47 empty
srw-rw-rw-   1 root    root        0 Jan  9 14:10 lmtp
drwxr-x---.  2 root    dovenull 4096 Jan 10 14:00 login
-rw-------   1 root    root        5 Jan 10 14:00 master.pid
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're running dovecot as user `vmail:vmail` (uid and gid 5000) while `/var/run/dovecot/auth-userdb` is owned by `root:root` with permissions of `0600`. You should either change mode to `0604` or change owner to `vmail` in `unix_listener auth-userdb` directive (2nd listing).

Comment: If you have this error, read this posting carefully.  It **does** contain the answer to your question.